# Can you use Xceed Grid for .NET to display right-to-left scripts, e.g. Arabic

Tags: .net, grid

Can the Xceed Grid for .NET control be used to display right-to-left text? I can't find any documentation or samples to do this. Does anyone know if it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

seems not, they don't fully support RTL, at least not for their grid control. you can, however, set the textboxes inside the grid to rtl, but that's only on the cell level...

i know, it's a pain in the butt to find any component provider to fully support RTL form/text display. your best option is microsoft's built in datagridview, OR just wait for visual studio 2010 :P